# Why doesn't the command Python not do anything in Command Prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, command-line

The Command Prompt does not do anything when I use the Python command to execute a module. It does not even do anything when I use it at all; it just pretends that I did not do anything, and goes back to the current working directory. Attached is a screen shot for clarity.

[image: Actual module]

[image: Not an actual module]

Comment: What is in the module? Is there actually a file named `gf` containing Python code?

Comment: It does not matter if it is a real module or not. If it is not a real module, then the CMD usually indicates that the file name does not exist; if it is a real module, it should run it. It does neither.

Comment: The only way I could replicate your problem was `echo "print()" >> gf` then `python gf`. Like @ShadowRanger mentioned, I'd check for a gf file on that dir... Everything else gives a visible error on the console.

Comment: There is no gf file on that directory. I was just quickly trying to make an example of the fact that when I add any characters after the "python" command, nothing happens; it just goes back to the working directory. Even if I am in a directory in which there is a python file, and I type, "python update.py", nothing happens; it just goes back to the working directory

Comment: Have you really tried to execute a script that `print`s something like e. g. `print("Hello, world")`?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelButscher The script uses the print command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update.

I simply uninstalled and reinstalled Python. Once I did that, the program works as it should in CMD.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, if you call `python` from Windows' Command Prompt (at least with my home computer), it will look for any python version installed using Windows Store, so if you just type `python`, it will open the Windows Store for you to install.

If you have Python installed, try to call full path to executable or try to add the path containing your Python executable (in my case, `C:\Python38`) to the system environment variable `PATH`:

1. Search for "Edit the system environment variables".
2. Click the `Environment variables...` button (in the Advanced tab)
3. Edit PATH and append `;C:\Python27` to the end (substitute your Python version)
4. Click OK and reopen `cmd` for change to take effect.

Comment: I have Python 3.8, so  does that mean `;C:\Python38`?

I see `Path` in the **System variables section**

So would I select that, click Edit again, and then add ` ;C:\Python38` to the end of `C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 11\ `?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but it depends on where your python installation is. You need to find the executable first (the installation folder)

Comment: I found the directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8

Comment: That’s the Start Menu shortcut. From here, you can right-click to any executable and click “Open file location”. It will lead you to the installation directory.

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

Comment: It appears that you are following the directions from this site: https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

This has to do with the error message that `python` is not a recognized command, which is not the situation at hand.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the answer, I managed to reproduce the error and also fix it on my home computer. It no longer shows that message since Python appears in Microsoft Store, so it just leads you there to install. But for older version of Windows, the computer actually doesn't know where the installation is, that's why it show ```python``` is not a recognised command.

Comment: Windows does **not** search for python in Windows store, it's a special python.exe file that does that. And modifying `%PATH%` isn't a good way to solve that. See [Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/q/1437590/241386) on how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you have python already installed, you should just be able to type 'python' alone then press enter. It should then give you a space to execute python code. It could be simple fix, but if not it's still worth a shot.

Comment: If I simply type `python` , it goes back to the working directory and the Microsoft Store opens up, saying that I own the app.

Answer (score 0):

When its the first time you're going to install python on Windows it shows you the option **Add to path** unchecked, so you just need to check that option and install python, you can uninstall python and installet again with the check, this fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the IDLE, it is the easiest way to run python scripts. Just open up IDLE and click on File < Open.. < and select your file. Then make any last minute changes and click on File < Save. Click on Run < Run Module (or F5) to run the python script. Done.

This is great for people that want to use python 2.7 or just don't want to install the python application from the Microsoft store.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the order in which the PATH environment variable is set also matters; if the Windows store variable is before the path where Python is installed then the windows store will open when you type python.